# Making HTTP requestfrom App Service with MSI to another App Service API using AAD authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

What I'm trying to do is make an authorized call from App Service 1 (*MainWebApp*) to App Service 2 (*AadAuthenticationApiOne - Dev*), using the MSI identity from App Service 1 which should get authorized positive on App Service 2.

While this shouldn't be too hard, I still fail to get this flow working. Probably because I'm missing some checkbox somewhere. I've tried multiple things, but started out clean again by following [Joonas Westlin's blogpost on the matter](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions).

This means I have an identity for my *MainWebApp* (Object Id: `bf00c7e8-b14b-4fe5-b768-da255026ff17`) and an App Registration for my second App Service, called *AadAuthenticationApiOne* (ObjectId - `9863b99a-6f28-4053-8a47-050f2b6da1e7` / Application Id - `905ceb2e-8bde-48ca-bcbd-937b0ed30e67`)

As described in the blogpost, I added an application role to the App Registration. Just for the sake of trying, I copy-pasted the complete block from his post in order to see if I got this working.

```js
{
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "Read all things",
      "id": "32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Allow the application to read all things as itself.",
      "value": "Things.Read.All"
    }
  ]
}
```

Afterwards, I added a new role assignment to my MSI for this new role by running the following script.

```bsh
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId bf00c7e8-b14b-4fe5-b768-da255026ff17 `
    -Id 32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81 `
    -PrincipalId bf00c7e8-b14b-4fe5-b768-da255026ff17 `
    -ResourceId 9863b99a-6f28-4053-8a47-050f2b6da1e7
```

In order to get an access token from my *MainWebApp* I've ran the following piece of code.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("905ceb2e-8bde-48ca-bcbd-937b0ed30e67", "b1f8cb55-7d7a-4e8d-9641-51372b423357");
// And I also tried the following
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://[mine].onmicrosoft.com/6c14b806-7fec-4423-88e9-ce535e07787a");
```

Both ways produce a valid JWT, which look familiar to the folliwing sample.

```js
{
  "aud": "905ceb2e-8bde-48ca-bcbd-937b0ed30e67",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/b1f8cb55-7d7a-4e8d-9641-51372b423357/",
  "iat": 1574427342,
  "nbf": 1574427342,
  "exp": 1574456442,
  "aio": "42VgYHjp+2hqNdcyiVLGhlfLNFomAAA=",
  "appid": "a4e07406-b556-4c4d-9525-5f410fd21fe7",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/b1f8cb55-7d7a-4e8d-9641-51372b423357/",
  "oid": "bf00c7e8-b14b-4fe5-b768-da255026ff17",
  "roles": [
    "Things.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "bf00c7e8-b14b-4fe5-b768-da255026ff17",
  "tid": "b1f8cb55-7d7a-4e8d-9641-51372b423357",
  "uti": "FrqIC0box0imFrEVC1ZHAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

However, when making a call to the API I'm receiving a page stating `Sign in to your account`.
The code for calling the API

```cs
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://myaadauthapi.azurewebsites.net/api/data");
```

The method in the API's controller looks like the following

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Things.Read.All")] //<-- Tried this one first, but didn't work
// [Authorize] // <-- Fallen back to this one, but didn't work either.
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new[]
    {
        "One",
        "Een",
        "1",
        "Uno"
    };
}
```

When invoking an endpoint which has the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute assigned to it, I get an expected result from the endpoint.

My guess is, my configuration in the API isn't correct (or something within Azure).

```
// The additions I did in the ConfigureServices method in Startup class
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    });

// And of course the addition to the Configure method
app.UseAuthentication();
```

With, of course, the application settings

```js
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "Domain": "[mine].onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "b1f8cb55-7d7a-4e8d-9641-51372b423357",
  "ClientId": "905ceb2e-8bde-48ca-bcbd-937b0ed30e67"
},
```

Just for good measure, I also added the *MainWebApp* as an Owner to the *AadAuthenticationApiOne*.
[image: MainWebApp assigned as Owner to AadAuthenticationApiOne - Access Control]

Comment: Thanks for reading my article :) It seems you have configured Azure AD authentication with OpenID Connect on the API. This is not the correct way. An API should be configured with Azure AD Bearer token authentication. It does not redirect requests, it requires access tokens. I have articles on that setup too ;)

Comment: I've probably done this because I'm kind of unfamiliar with this stuff. Will do some searching on your blog right away. Thanks for pointing out the mistake I made.

Comment: Here's a link to the first part: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1

Comment: I found it and fixed it! Thanks! If you link it in an answer I'll immediately mark it as answered. Will do some more studying on the matter to try understanding what I'm actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have configured Azure AD authentication with OpenID Connect on the API. This is not the correct way. An API should be configured with Azure AD Bearer token authentication. It does not redirect requests, it requires access tokens. I have articles on that setup too ;)

https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1